# Partitioned table on timestamp::date query scanning all partitions

Tags: postgresql, time, timezone, partitioning, postgresql-9.6

### Problem setting (Postgesql 9.6)

I have one table where partitioning works as I intended(1), one that does not(2):

### CASE(1)

Table, partitioning on s_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL

```
CREATE TABLE "diagnoseAW"."AWIORECORDERAWCOMMAND"
(
    "ebpZone" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "elementName" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    command text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    s_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    i_io_value text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    source text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    time_created timestamp with time zone,
    user_created text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT "AWIORECORDERAWCOMMAND_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ebpZone", "elementName", command, s_date, i_io_value)
        USING INDEX TABLESPACE s1297_index
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE s1297_data;
```

Partitions look like this :

```
CREATE TABLE partitions."AWIORECORDERAWCOMMAND_2018_02_20"
(
    "ebpZone" ,
    "elementName" ,
    command ,
    s_date ,
    i_io_value ,
    source ,
    time_created ,
    user_created ,
    CONSTRAINT "AWIORECORDERAWCOMMAND_2018_02_20_NEW_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ebpZone", "elementName", command, s_date, i_io_value)
        USING INDEX TABLESPACE s1297_data,
    CONSTRAINT "AWIORECORDERAWCOMMAND_2018_02_20_s_date_check" CHECK (s_date::date = '2018-02-20'::date)
)
    INHERITS ("diagnoseAW"."AWIORECORDERAWCOMMAND")
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE s1297_data;
```

When I execute this query:

```
SELECT "ebpZone", "elementName", command, s_date, i_io_value, source, time_created, user_created
                FROM "diagnoseAW"."AWIORECORDERAWCOMMAND"
                WHERE s_date::date = '2018-02-20'::date;
```

It works fine, it scans only the wanted partition :

```
"Append  (cost=0.00..3083.05 rows=610 width=48)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on "AWIORECORDERAWCOMMAND"  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=208)"
"        Filter: ((s_date)::date = '2018-02-20'::date)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on "AWIORECORDERAWCOMMAND_2018_02_20"  (cost=0.00..3083.05 rows=609 width=48)"
"        Filter: ((s_date)::date = '2018-02-20'::date)"
```

### CASE(2):

Table, partitioning on "startDate" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL

```
CREATE TABLE "diagnoseAW"."AWIORECORDERMOVEMENT"
(
    event text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "ebpZone" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "awName" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "startDate" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "lossDate" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "controlDate" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "startDuration" numeric,
    "totalDuration" numeric,
    time_created timestamp with time zone,
    user_created text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "lossEnd" boolean,
    "controlEnd" boolean,
    railtemp double precision,
    airtemp double precision,
    CONSTRAINT "AWIORECORDERMOVEMENT_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ebpZone", "awName", "startDate", "lossDate", "controlDate")
        USING INDEX TABLESPACE s1297_index
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE s1297_data;
```

Partitions look like this :

```
CREATE TABLE partitions."AWIORECORDERMOVEMENT_2018_02_20"
(
    event ,
    "ebpZone" ,
    "awName" ,
    "startDate" ,
    "lossDate" ,
    "controlDate" ,
    "startDuration" ,
    "totalDuration" ,
    time_created ,
    user_created ,
    "lossEnd" ,
    "controlEnd" ,
    railtemp ,
    airtemp ,
    CONSTRAINT "AWIORECORDERMOVEMENT_2018_02_20_NEW_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ebpZone", "awName", "startDate", "lossDate", "controlDate")
        USING INDEX TABLESPACE s1297_data,
    CONSTRAINT "AWIORECORDERMOVEMENT_2018_02_20_startDate_check" CHECK ("startDate"::date = '2018-02-20'::date)
)
    INHERITS ("diagnoseAW"."AWIORECORDERMOVEMENT")
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE s1297_data;
```

When I execute this query:

```
SELECT event, "ebpZone", "awName", "startDate", "lossDate", "controlDate", "startDuration", "totalDuration", time_created, user_created, "lossEnd", "controlEnd", railtemp, airtemp
FROM "diagnoseAW"."AWIORECORDERMOVEMENT"
WHERE "startDate"::date='2018-02-20'::date;
```

It does not work fine, it scans all partitions :

```
"Append  (cost=0.00..1386483.44 rows=241434 width=80)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on "AWIORECORDERMOVEMENT"  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=242)"
"        Filter: (("startDate")::date = '2018-02-20'::date)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on "AWIORECORDERMOVEMENT_2017_01_02"  (cost=0.00..2566.48 rows=446 width=80)"
"        Filter: (("startDate")::date = '2018-02-20'::date)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on "AWIORECORDERMOVEMENT_2017_01_07"  (cost=0.00..1588.55 rows=276 width=80)"
"        Filter: (("startDate")::date = '2018-02-20'::date)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on "AWIORECORDERMOVEMENT_2017_01_09"  (cost=0.00..3137.61 rows=546 width=80)"
"        Filter: (("startDate")::date = '2018-02-20'::date)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on "AWIORECORDERMOVEMENT_2017_01_12"  (cost=0.00..3279.47 rows=569 width=80)"
"        Filter: (("startDate")::date = '2018-02-20'::date)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on "AWIORECORDERMOVEMENT_2017_01_13"  (cost=0.00..3390.38 rows=589 width=80)"
"        Filter: (("startDate")::date = '2018-02-20'::date)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on "AWIORECORDERMOVEMENT_2017_01_16"  (cost=0.00..3139.07 rows=546 width=80)"
"        Filter: (("startDate")::date = '2018-02-20'::date)"
```

...

### Question

The only difference that I see is the with or without timestamp in the timestamp I use for partitioning. (Also in the second case the partitions have indexes, not in the first case but I think it's not relevant)
Any ideas how I can make a query that will not scan all my partitions for CASE(2)? Preferably I would not reload all the billions of rows.

Comment: We found no way to get it right, we ended up altering the table converting the column from timestamp with time zone to timestamp without time zone in just under three hours

Comment: It's certainly an interesting issue though. I might look into it if I have time at some point.